# Why doesn't my asset image load the first time but loads on the second time when I build my app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an app in flutter and whenever I build it for the first time the image doesn't load.But when I rerun it,it loads.Why does that happen.

Here is the screenshot of the error when I run for the first time

[image: Error]

Code to loaf the images:

```
 final _pages_images = [
    Image.asset("assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/Group 5.png", fit: BoxFit.fill),
    Image.asset(
      "assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/Group 6.png",
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    Image.asset(
      "assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/Group.png",
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    )
  ];

Widget _buildPageView() {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: _pageController,
      itemCount: _pages_images.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
        child: _pages_images[index],
      ),
      onPageChanged: (int index) =>
          setState(() => _currentPageNotifier = index),
    );
  }
```

pubspec.yaml file:

```
  assets:
    - assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/Group 5.png
    - assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/Group 6.png
    - assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/Group.png
```

Comment: I assume the assets are unavailable to the flutter program until re-run is performed, when you make any additions to the `pubspec.yaml` file, you need to run `flutter pub get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify each file, you can include the directory.

```
  assets:
    - assets/FirstScreenImages/mdpi/
```

Now regarding your problem, if possible I suggest avoiding the use of spaces in file names and paths regardless of the programming language or OS, IMHO "Group_6.png" is just as pretty as "Group 6.png" and you don't have to worry if errors will pop up because of something as trivial as a space character.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47705) on flutter's github page that describes exactly the same problem you are having (path contains a space: first run gives an error, but when doing hot reload it stops giving errors). You might get it to work with spaces if you switch flutter version, but honestly it is just so much easier not to use the space character (if possible).

Comment: You are right,after removing the spaces,now it is fine.Thanks.I have marked ur answer as correct